# Python3 migration xml write issue

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Currently frustrated with code migration to Python3 (3.6.8)

out_fname is a .cproject file (xml format)

```
self.cproject_xml = ET.parse(self.CPROJ_NAME))
with open(out_fname, 'a') as cxml:
     cxml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n')
     cxml.write('<?fileVersion 4.0.0?>')
     self.cproject_xml.write(cxml,encoding='utf-8')
```

leads to:

```
  File "/home/build/workspace/bismuth_build_nightly_py3@2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tinlane/cprojecttools.py", line 209, in export_cproject
    self.cproject_xml.write(fxml)
    snips..
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 946, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(elem.tail))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I have tried all different ways (be careful, i need the "a" when opening my file) to make it work (posting original python2 code, not the alternates). Usually i just placed a "b" in r,a,w which would solve the problem. No it doesn't work:

```
(cxml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')
```

even when i convert to bytes (wrong in my opinion)

Minimal Example to reproduce:
create 2 identical files (file1, file2) with the following content:

```
<note>
  <to>minimal</to>
  <from>xml</from>
  <heading>file</heading>
  <body>content</body>
</note>
```

and run this codeblock:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

cproject_xml = ET.parse('file1')
fname = 'file2'
with open(fname, 'a') as cxml:
     cxml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n')
     cxml.write('<?fileVersion 4.0.0?>')
     cproject_xml.write(cxml,encoding='utf-8')
```

When run with python2, file2 becomes:

```
<note>
  <to>minimal</to>
  <from>xml</from>
  <heading>file</heading>
  <body>content</body>
</note>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?fileVersion 4.0.0?><note>
  <to>minimal</to>
  <from>xml</from>
  <heading>file</heading>
  <body>content</body>
</note>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please post self-contained code that can be copy-pasted and run ([mcve]). What is `out_fname`?

Comment: thanks, you're right. It's a .cproject Eclipse file (xml format)

Comment: Hope it's ok now, added a simple example

Comment: What are file1 and file2 supposed to look like after you run your code?

Comment: This code runs normally with python2. So the output is provided when run with the old version.

Comment: Updated with python2 output which is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure I'm missing something but it doesn't make sense try to write the tree (`cproject_xml`) to the open file handle (`cxml`).

I think it would make more sense to serialize the tree and write directly to the open file.

Try changing:

```py
cproject_xml.write(cxml, encoding='utf-8')
```

to:

```py
cxml.write(ET.tostring(cproject_xml.getroot()).decode())
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, this indeed solves the problem as i could not think out of the box. Marking as solved, however it would be interesting if the problem could be solved the way it is. Fxml is a TextWrapper obj so i was wondering if this can be converted somehow.